# How to Stub navigation in XCUI

Tags: swift, xcode, xcuitest, stubbing

i have my my app in a different target and my test in a different target. i want to navigate to a specified page directly when i open the app. when saves time in automation rather than accessing the UI element each time to navigate to the specific page.

Answer (score 1):

To my opinion, the best way to do this is to implement URL Schemes in your app
https://www.appcoda.com/working-url-schemes-ios/

These schemes enhance your app in many ways

- Users will be able to open the required content in your app instantly (by opening URL, scanning QR code etc)
- Developers can use URLs as launch environment variables to debug the application quicker
- QA Engineers will benefit from using launch environment as well (in a scenario from your question)

Read the documentation to know how to set up app launch
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/xcuiapplication/1500427-launchenvironment
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/xcuiapplication/1500477-launcharguments